locally Lipschitz of a epidemiological system
let
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
d X(t)=F(X(t)), \\
X(0)=X_0 \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^7 .
\end{array}\right.
$$
where
$$
X(t)=\left(X_i(t)\right)_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant 7}=\left(M(t), S(t), H_1(t), H_2(t), H_1 S(t), H_2 S(t), C(t)\right),
$$
and
$$
F(X(t))=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\Lambda+\gamma S-\left(\lambda_S+\lambda_H+\delta\right) M \\
\lambda_S M-\left(\gamma+\theta_2 \lambda_H+\delta_S\right) S \\
\lambda_H M+\rho_1 \gamma H_1 S-\left(\theta_1 \lambda_S+r_1+\delta+\delta_H+\alpha\right) H_1 \\
\alpha H_1-\left(\beta+r_2+\delta+\delta_H\right) H_2 \\
\theta_2 \lambda_H S+\left(\theta_1 \lambda_S+r_1\right) H_1-\left(\rho_1 \gamma+\rho_2 \alpha+\delta_H+\delta_S+\delta\right) H_1 S \\
\rho_2 \alpha H_1 S+r_2 H_2-\left(\rho_3 \beta+\delta_S+\delta_H+\delta\right) H_2 S \\
\beta H_2+\rho_3 \beta H_2 S-\left(\delta+\delta_H\right) C
\end{array}\right) .
$$
with $\lambda_H=\phi_H\left(H_1+c_1 H_1 S\right)$ and $\lambda_S=\phi_S\left(S+c_2 H_1 S\right)$
I want to prove that F is locally Lipschitz.
I don't know how to proceed. if it was just a combination of $X_i$ it's clear but in this case i have non linear combination due to $\lambda_H$ and $\lambda_s$

Differentiability at a point implies locally Lipschitz in some neighborhood of that point. As long as $\phi_H$ and $\phi_S$ are smooth enough, you should be fine.
